# conflict between Spyder and wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, spyder

I am new in wxPython. Starting from a simple tutorial (http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20by%20Example), it seems that there is a conflict between Spyder and wxPython. 
I can run the following script once (in the IPython console), using:

```
runfile(r'C:\Python27\Scripts\test\test.py')
```

which contains:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(350,200))

app = wx.App(redirect=True)
top = Frame("Hello World")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

But the second time I run it, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 493, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\test\test.py", line 14, in <module>
top = Frame("Hello World")
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\test\test.py", line 11, in __init__
wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(350,200))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_windows.py", line 505, in __init__
_windows_.Frame_swiginit(self,_windows_.new_Frame(*args, **kwargs))
PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!
```

It do not really understand but apparently it is related to the fact that spyder is written using wxPython and a conflict with the app.MainLoop()

Could someone confirm and/or explain a little bit more ?

Thanks a lot,

Patrick

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it's because you are attempting to run the example in an interactive interpreter session. The example is really a GUI application with an event loop, and it's not going to behave well when you repeatedly execute it in the same interactive session since cleanup of the previous app from the last run won't happen completely. Like you experienced, it will run once, but subsequent attempts fail. Such an example should definitely be run in its own dedicated interpreter that can completely exit when the GUI closes.

In Spyder, you can configure your script to run in a dedicated stand-alone interpreter without having to manually run in a separate external console. Open the file in the Spyder editor, hit F6 to open the Run Settings dialog, and then select the radio button for "Execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter". Now hit Run. Subsequent runs by using F5 will remember this configuration setting, and you'll get your example running in it's own interpreter with each repeated execution.

Comment: Excelent, solved my problem too, but I had to hit CTRL-F6 to open the settings dialog (Spider 3.2.3), not just F6.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's the same issue that you can run into when you run wxPython applications using IDLE, the tkinter based Python IDE that comes with Python. Basically you end up having two main loops and while it works sometimes, other times they get into conflict and you get weird errors like this one. I think when you have two wx.Apps running, you're in "undefined" land, which is a "bad" thing. Just run your applications from IPython itself, the command line or some other way where there won't be two wx event loops.

Comment: Hello. Thank you Mike for your quick answer. It is indeed what I am currently doing : saving the *.py file and launching it via a "stand-alone" console... No so userfriendly for development but I will survive :-) I am now thinking using pyDev (plug-in of Eclipse) which is apparently not based on wxPython to develop my GUI.... I will put my findings on this post ! Thanks again.

Comment: You can use Spyder or IDLE for development, just don't run the script from within it. I currently use Wingware's IDE. Komodo has a free edition http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit. Or you can try PyDev. I personally don't like the Eclipse environment very much.